# How to bind a (basic) Kendo DropDownList made from a select element, with data in option elements, to a javascript object using Kendo MVVM?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I can't seem to work out, or see examples any where in the doco or on the web for how to do this.

I have a simple select element that I have marked up to be a Kendo DropDownList.

HTML:

```
<div id="View">
    <select
    id="DropDownList"
    data-role="dropdownlist"
    data-value-primitive="true"
    data-bind="value: OptionID">
        <option value="1">Option One</option>
        <option value="2">Option Two</option>
        <option value="3">Option Three</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oDataSource = {
        OptionID: -1
    };
    // MVVM Bind View to Record
    kendo.bind($('#View'), oDataSource);
    // Log OptionID set in oDataSource by DropDownListing Binding
    $('#DropDownList').data('kendoDropDownList').bind('select', function (e) {
        console.log('Selected Option: ' + oDataSource.OptionID);
    });
});
```

The console.log of the oDataSource.OptionID shows -1 every time.

I have created a fiddle here that demonstrates the code above: http://jsfiddle.net/codeowl/CDrFS/3/

What am I doing wrong?

Regards,

Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two questions:

1. You should define `oDataSource` as an `ObservableObject` otherwise your variable is not bound to `DropDownList`.
2. You need to use `change` handler instead since `select` is triggered when the option is selected but the `input` is not changed yet.

So your code should be:

```
var oDataSource = kendo.observable({
    OptionID: -1
});

// MVVM Bind View to Record
kendo.bind($('#View'), oDataSource);

// Log OptionID set in oDataSource by DropDownListing Binding
$('#DropDownList').data('kendoDropDownList').bind('change', function (e) {
    console.log('Selected Option: ' + oDataSource.OptionID);
});
```

See you JSFiddle modified here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/CDrFS/4/

Comment: Great work mate.  Thanks for your assistance, much appreciated.